# При установке mysql 57 на Oracle Linux 6.9 - Error: Package

Tags: mysql, linux

Здравствуйте.

На ОС Linux

```
Oracle Linux Server release 6.9
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="6.9"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="6.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 6.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:6:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 6"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.9
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.9
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
Oracle Linux Server release 6.9
```

пытаюсь установить из репозитория

mysql 5.7

```
yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

получаю ошибку

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.0.1.el6_8.x86_64 (@public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_7.1.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64 (public_ol6_latest)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь установить **файл** *mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm*. Делать так можно только в самых простых случаях, когда пакет не имеет зависимостей. Вам выдаются сообщения о нарушенных зависимостях. Для того, что бы система управления **пакетами** могла автоматически разобраться с зависимостями пакета, нужно и устанавливать **пакет**.

Проще всего, для этого, запустить графический интерфейс системы управления пакетами (не знаю, что у Вас - gnorpm или  kdeadmin), с помощью функции поиска найти пакет *mysql* (Может оказаться, что версия именно 5.7 отсутствует) и установить **пакет**. Все зависимости будут разрешены автоматически.

Comment: к сожалению вынужден был констатировать, что mysql 57 не может быть установлена на oracle linux 6.9 из-за  версии библиотеки glibc, в oracle linux 6.9 - 2.12, а необходима 2.17